# Search consecutive indices in string

Tags: python

I am new to python and i am trying to search for words in strings i.e if index[0][1][2] is bob and index [2][3][4] is bob, i want to find two results. I am completely lost in this.

```
i = 0
indexes =  [i][+i][++i]
start = 0
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
slen = len('azcbobobegghakl')
b = s.index('bob')
print slen

if [i][+i][++i] in s == 'bob':
start += 1
print start
```

Comment: My code does not make sense for now since i keep changing things

Comment: do you want the count or the index of the substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for slicing:

```
>>> s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
>>> print s[3:6]
bob
```

In python, the `++i` syntax doesn't exist (it doesn't do what you think it does). You need to do `[i:i+3]`.

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
>>> i = range(len(s)) # i = [0, 1, 2, 3, ...,  14]
>>> s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
>>> for number in i:
...     if s[number:number+3] == 'bob': 
...         print 'I found bob!'
... 
I found bob!
I found bob!
```

Comment: Yeah, but what about [5:8]? pretty much i would like to start searching from index[0:3] with increments of 1 for the length of string

Comment: Perfect! this is great.